# Does Azure Synapse SQL DW deployment is similar to SQL DB deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am designing a Azure Synapse SQL DW CI-CD pipeline. Is CI/CD logic is same for Azure Synapse SQL (formerly SQL DW) and SQL DB, which is to create a DACPAC file and deploy?

Does anyone has deployed or have some poc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2019 you can create a project type of `SQL Server Database Project` (you may [have to install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2019)), set the project type to `Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse` and that will work for **dedicated SQL pools**.

[image: VS2019 and SSDT projects]

For serverless SQL pools, this is not supported at this time.  You can however use the Azure DevOps DACPAC deployment task to deploy SQL scripts only rather than compiled DACPACs.

In Azure DevOps, make sure the agent you use is Windows 2019 or above as that will have the right version of `sqlpackage.exe`.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of a pipeline to deploy Azure Synapse:

```
strategy:
  runOnce:
    deploy:
      steps:
      - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask - ProjectA'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '[subscription-name]'
          ServerName: '$(database-server)'
          DatabaseName: '$(database-name)'
          SqlUsername: '$(database-user)'
          SqlPassword: '$(database-user-password)'
          DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/_dacpac/database.dacpac'
```